# How to show Web Browser in Visual Studio 2019 Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

When I try to use Web Browser in the windows form application. Unable to found any web browser control. Then I use web browser class to create a browser within form Load.

**Problem:** Unable to show web browser in windows form load using bellow code.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webBrowser.Width = this.Width;
        webBrowser.Height = this.Height;
        //webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));
        webBrowser.Url = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
        webBrowser.Visible = true;
        webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowser.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Replace `webBrowser.Show();` with `this.Controls.Add(webBrowser);`. Declare the WebBrowser object as a Field. Dispose of it when the Form closes. Or install [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/). You didn't mention either the Project's Framework or Visual Studio versions.

Comment: You may want to look at the new MS Edge WebView2 NuGet package. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jimi is right. We browser need to add within form control.

Working code snippet.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webBrowser.Width = this.Width;
        webBrowser.Height = this.Height;
        //webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));
        webBrowser.Url = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
        webBrowser.Visible = true;
        webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        this.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
    }
```